# Opening XML files with notepad program in Windows mobile 6/6.5

Tags: xml, windows, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

So,

I have a windows mobile 6 application, written with .NET CF which loads its settings from an XML file. The problem is that windows 6.5 opens xml files using the browser and I don't see any "open with" option anywhere.

I am using a free application called notepad mobile, which is great but using its open file function I am unable to browse to the program files folder (only to my documents).

Ideally I'd like to be able to edit the xml file from the mobile itself.

So my question, is there a registry entry to make the program files folder "visible" or something of the sort ?

and if not is there an alternative to this ?

I know I can put my program files in my documents folder ... but I'd like to avoid that

Thanks in advance

Comment: My guess is this free app was only written to look into the My Documents folder. You might want to contact that vendor to see if they make another version that can read from other directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are touching some 'defaults' in windows mobile.

1.) as on desktop windows, file extensions are associated with applications (or not). This is controlled by the device's registry (as on desktop windows):
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.xml]
"Content Type"="text/xml"
"Default"="xmlfile"
--and--
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xmlfile\Shell\Open\Command]
"Default"="iexplore.exe file:%1"
You now can change the latter setting and insert your custom app to open xml files as default xml file handler.

2.) the default OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog is restricted to the MyDocuments folder. This is by Windows Mobile OS design. As long as a programmer does not implement a custom open/save file dialog, you will not be able to open/save files outside the My Documents and persistent storage volumes (like an SD card). You may try to enter a full path in the standard dialogs (but I assume that it is not supported).

I would recommend you either change the setting as in 1.) or use a file browser with editor like TotalCommander CE (FREEWARE: http://www.ghisler.com/ce.htm).

have fun

Josef

Comment: Excellent heads-up about TotalCommander - Just what I needed as well.